# Ruby Time to JavaScript Date in Chrome/Firefox

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, time

My Rails application returns JSON object with two Time attributes as a String but Firefox doesn't parse them correctly to Date objects.

A sample JSON object:

```
{ 
  from: '/Date(2014-11-14 11:26:00)/',
  to:   '/Date(2014-11-15 12:00:00)/',
  ... 
}
```

The JSON objects are created with the following Ruby method:

```
def create_json
  {
    from: '/Date(' + (self.starts_at.to_s) + ')/',
    to: '/Date(' + (self.ends_at.to_s) + ')/',
    ...
  }
```

In order to parse the JSON object, a regex extracts the argument from the string value and passes it as a string or a numeric value to the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Syntax) constructor and tries to instantiate two new Date objects:

```
 var from = new Date('2014-11-14 11:26:00')
 var to = new Date('2014-11-15 12:00:00')
```

This works in Chrome but fails in Firefox.

Comment: Why to you call `to_s` on the dates instead of just `to_json`?

Comment: I'm using a library which requires this format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested a couple of Ruby (on Rails) methods to find out which works best to instantiate new Date objects in JavaScript. The results are:

### Ruby Class Time .to_s ([Link](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Time.html#method-i-to_s)):

The output of this method **works in Google Chrome** but **doesn't work in Firefox**.

### Rails .to_formatted_s(:rfc822) ([Link](http://apidock.com/rails/Time/to_formatted_s)):

The output of this method **works in Google Chrome** and **works limited in Firefox**.

It didn't work for me in Firefox when I was trying to parse dateStrings that were using German day abbreviations (e.g. 'Do, 13 Nov 2014 ...' instead of 'Thu, 13 Nov 2014 ...')

### Ruby Class Time .to_i.to_s ([Link](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Time.html#method-i-to_i))

The output of this method **doesn't work in Google Chrome** and **doesn't work in Firefox** either because it returns **seconds instead of milliseconds** since the Epoch.

### converted Ruby class Time (... .to_i * 1000).to_s:

The output of this method **works in Google Chrome and in Firefox** - finally ;-).

Hope this saves you some pain!